# How to download pdf from a hyperlink requiring login information in outlook by VBA

Tags: html, vba, outlook, hyperlink

I use outlook to receive my emails(cannot change this...), I want to find a way in windows to automatically process one kind of my emails which have download links.

I want to find a way to selectively download files from the emails with key words.

The procedures I can think of to achieve this is:

1. search my emails with key words
2. find the hyperlink in the emails with the key words
3. download the files and save them in a folder.

My current code is :

```
Sub Search_Inbox()

Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myitems As Outlook.Items

Dim bodyString As String
Dim bodyStringLines
Dim splitLine

Dim hyperlink As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim found As Integer  

Set olFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("lll@163.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("abc")
Set myitems = olFolder.Items

i = 0
found = 0

'find the hyperlink in the emails"
For Each myitem In myitems
    If InStr(1, myitem.Body, "passed", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then            
        If InStr(1, myitem.Body, "tested", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'inside the target email, search for the key word
        bodyString = myitem.Body
        bodyStringLines = Split(bodyString, vbCrLf)
        For Each splitLine In bodyStringLines
            i = i + 1
            keyStart = InStr(splitLine, "keyword")
            keyEnd = keyStart + Len("keyword") - 1
            If found = 0 Then
                If keyStart > 0 Then
                    If keyEnd = Len(splitLine) Then
                        found = 1
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                hyperlink = splitLine
                found = 0
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print "hyperlink is"
        Debug.Print hyperlink           
        'DownloadFile1 (hyperlink)
        'DownloadFile2 (hyperlink)
        End If

    Else
        Found = False
    End If
Next

Set olFolder = Nothing
Set myitems = Nothing

End Sub
```

But I have a problem at the downloading part. The access to the hyperlink requires filling the login information. I tried the following two methods but failed...

```
Sub DownloadFile1(myURL As String)

    Dim saveDirectoryPath As String

    '*******************************
    ' Intitial setup
    '*******************************
    saveDirectoryPath = "C:\testfile.pdf" 'where your files will be stored
    '*******************************

    Dim fileNameArray() As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim arrayLength As Integer
    Dim DateString As String
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")

    fileNameArray = Split(myURL, "/")
    arrayLength = UBound(fileNameArray)
    fileName = fileNameArray(arrayLength)

    'Add date to the file incase there are duplicates comment out these lines if you do not want the date added
    fileName = Replace(fileName, ".pdf", "_" & DateString & ".pdf")
    fileName = Replace(fileName, ".PDF", "_" & DateString & ".PDF")

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
    WinHttpReq.Send

    myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile saveDirectoryPath & fileName, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

I failed (Access is denied) in line :

```
 WinHttpReq.Send
```

---

I also tried the following code.

```
Sub DownloadFile2(myURL As String)

Dim strCookie As String, strResponse As String, _
  strUrl As String
  Dim xobj As Object
  Dim WinHttpReq As Object
  Set xobj = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

  UN = "username"
  PW = "password"

  strUrl = "https://www.jedec.org/user/login"
  xobj.Open "POST", strUrl, False
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  xobj.Send "username=" & UN & "&password=" & PW & "&login=login"
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseText

  strUrl = myURL 
  xobj.Open "GET", strUrl, False

  xobj.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
  xobj.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
  xobj.Send

  strCookie = xobj.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
  strResponse = xobj.ResponseBody

 If xobj.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write xobj.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\testfile.pdf", 1
    oStream.Close
End If
End Sub
```

2018/03/01 problem (solved ): User-defined type not defined, at line:

```
Set xobj = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
```

Solved: Here is a trick that you should include the reference of Microsoft WinHTTP Service.

2018/03/02 problem (unsolved): The URL does not use a recognized protocol, at line:
xobj.Open "GET", strUrl, False

---

### Anyone has any ideas about how to fix this?

reference for extracting information from email body:

https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/extract-show-hyperlink-addresses-email-via-outlook-vba/

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?49021-Download-File-from-Hyperlink-in-Body-of-Emailhttp://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?49021-Download-File-from-Hyperlink-in-Body-of-Email

---

reference for downloading file from hyperlink which requires login info. :

[How to download a PDF that is in a hyperlink using VB in Outlook 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679448/how-to-download-a-pdf-that-is-in-a-hyperlink-using-vb-in-outlook-2016/44686511#44686511)

[Vba download file from internet WinHttpReq with login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863408/vba-download-file-from-internet-winhttpreq-with-login-not-working)

Comment: You can use VBA within outlook to do this, but a question like this is too broad for SO.  Try something out, then post back with code if you run into problems.

Comment: You can create a Sub in a normal module, to initiate when an Outlook rule for certain conditions are met. In that Sub, process the mail body for the link(s). Depends on where it links to, you may need different approaches for each site. The requirement is that you need to keep the Outlook running.

Comment: Do you know how to search for key words in the email body by VBA

Comment: OK. Search for key word, this problem is solved. Current problem is about how to find a hyperlink in the emai.

Comment: To use Word from other applications you have to either set a reference to Word or use late binding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24263432

Comment: Thank you!! I will try this. Do you know how to search a key word and only open the hyperlink after the key word? What method I can use to achieve this.

Comment: Can you show example of the hyperlink ?

Comment: I have updated the email example. Please see the question description